# Close a Looping Thread make the script freezes

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Introduction

I have been made some script with threading inside of it to kill exe's for certain amount of time. The threading seems working fine but when im going to close the script, it freezes. My script has a "button" to execute and exit using TKinter

## Problematic

The script become freezes and the thread stil going on the background. The thread contain loops for 30-60 seconds (killing exe's). It seems the script cant close properly because of the thread still going on and on.

Here's the thread class :

```
# Global Variable #
runBroke='taskkill /F /im RuntimeBroker.exe'

#Thread  Class #
    class Killizer(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.thread1 = None
            self.stop_threads = Event()
    
        def killer(self):
            while not self.stop_threads.is_set():
                def kill():
                    os.system(runBroke)
                    timer()
                def timer():
                    time.sleep(60)
                    kill()
                kill()
    
        def exe(self):
            self.stop_threads.clear()
            self.thread1 = Thread(target = self.killer)
            self.thread1.start()
    
        def shut(self):
            self.stop_threads.set()
            self.thread1.join()
            self.thread1 = None
```

How to properly close or enforce to exit that thread using TKinter Button?

Comment: `os.system` returns more or less immediately, are you sure you need a Thread around ?

Comment: I have no choice to make it looping (killing multiple times indefinitely) to kill the exe's, so i put it inside a "thread" other than put it on the main function that one time execution. @MauriceMeyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `after` making a timer to kill the application:

```
import time, os
import tkinter as tk

runBroke='taskkill /F /im RuntimeBroker.exe'

class KillingApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.kill()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def _kill(self):
        print("running: taskkill")
        os.system(runBroke)

    def kill(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.label.configure(text="Last kill time: %s" % now)
        self._kill()
        # idle 5 seconds
        self.root.after(5000, self.kill)

app=KillingApp()
```

Comment: I never heard thread can be idled like that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

use ... at the end

```
# Global Variable #
runBroke='taskkill /F /im RuntimeBroker.exe'

#Thread  Class #
    class Killizer(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.thread1 = None
            self.stop_threads = Event()
    
        def killer(self):
            while not self.stop_threads.is_set():
                def kill():
                    os.system(runBroke)
                    timer()
                def timer():
                    time.sleep(60)
                    kill()
                kill()
    
        def exe(self):
            self.stop_threads.clear()
            self.thread1 = Thread(target = self.killer)
            self.thread1.start()
    
        def shut(self):
            self.stop_threads.set()
            self.thread1.join()
            self.thread1 = None
```

it will close it all cleanly

Comment: Adding "...." ? What the dots do at the end of the class?

Comment: then you can add code after the ... and it continues the code without closing the hole thing. it works for me

Comment: I think that not needed. Like just write in words, that are more understandable to people.

Comment: it closes off doesnt it?

Comment: Where should i put it? At the end of that "class" or the "shut" function? Your parenthesize is a bit confusing. Sorry, but can you hightlight all the code and use the "code wrapper" again? @HELPMEPLEASE

Comment: Why dont use sys.exit

Comment: I have tried using "raise.systemExit(0)" after using "self.stop_threads" and its not work. I might going to try it using "sys.exit" @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer

Comment: I have many function inside that script including "else if", im sure it would be some errors because "..." not defined. @HELPMEPLEASE